# Odoo 8: Nested form view of Many2one field

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

I am in the process of refactoring a model (let's call it `Parent`), which stores a number of Many2one fields that reference records of the same model (`Child`). The `Parent` form view contains a `notebook` and each `page` displays details for a specific `Child`, currently described within the `page` in a repetitive fashion and with lots of related fields. I'm trying to avoid the repetition in the view, and get rid of the need for the related fields.

```
class Child(models.Model):
    _name = "child"

   # ...

class Parent(models.Model):
    _name = "parent"

   child_1 = fields.Many2one('child', 'Child 1')
   child_1_age = fields.Float(related='child_1.age', string='Child Age')
   # ...
   child_2 = fields.Many2one('child', 'Child 2')
   child_2_age = fields.Float(related='child_2.age', string='Child Age')
   # ...


<!-- ... -->
<field name="model">parent</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <notebook colspan="8" col="8">
        <page>
            <!-- buttons, a bunch of related Child fields, etc -->
        </page>
        <page>
            <!-- buttons, a bunch of related Child fields, etc -->
        </page>
    </notebook>
</field>
```

I have a special form view defined for the `Child`, but I don't know how to insert it in the `notebook` pages of the `Parent` view. Since it is possible to insert tree views in forms (like for One2many fields for example), I guess there has to be a way to do it with forms as well. An example how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated.

Please ignore any syntax errors, the above is just a simple visual representation to help better describe my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `widget` attribute in order to assign a widget to your relational field, for example

```
<field name="my_field" widget="my_widget"/>
```

To see an example as to how a widget works and is created take a look at the following example:

Go to `addons/account/project/wizard/account_analytic_journal_report_view.xml` and see the line that defines a `many2many_tags` widget.

This form widget is assigned on `addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js` at around line 6396 that comments `Registry of form fields ...`

The `many2many_tags` string that we used is assigned a actual widget, that widget has a template, and that template is rendered in place of your field.

**TL;DR** Give a [widget](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#widgets) element to your field, define that widget, assign that widget to work on a template and create the template that contains your view.

Comment: Thanks for your input, George. I was hoping for a more straightforward way to do it, but this seems like an approach that should work. I'll try it when I get the chance and if I make it work, will post the example here for reference.